# KSP on Kotlin Multiplatform fails on the kspJs with "Collection has more than one element."

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-symbol-processing

I'm experimenting with KSP (Kotlin Symbol Processing) to see what it's capable of and I'm trying to get it working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project.
When I only enable kspJvm, it works perfectly, as soon as I enable kspJs as well, it fails with "Collection has more than one element."

I've recreated the issue in this demo github project:
https://github.com/janvladimirmostert/observable-demo

In my **processor**, I have the following config:

**build.gradle.kts**:

```
val kspVersion: String by project

group = "io.jvaas"

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:$kspVersion")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**gradle.properties**:

```
kotlinVersion=1.6.0
kspVersion=1.6.0-1.0.1
```

src/commonMain/kotlin/io/jvaas/observe/**Observable.kt**

```
package io.jvaas.observe

annotation class Observable
```

src/jvmMain/resources/META-INF/services/**com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.SymbolProcessorProvider**

```
io.jvaas.observe.ObservableProcessorProvider
```

src/jvmMain/kotlin/io/jvaas/observe/**ObservableProcessor.kt**

```
class ObservableProcessor(
    val codeGenerator: CodeGenerator,
    val logger: KSPLogger,
) : SymbolProcessor {

    ...

}

class ObservableProcessorProvider : SymbolProcessorProvider {
    override fun create(
        environment: SymbolProcessorEnvironment
    ): SymbolProcessor {
        return ObservableProcessor(environment.codeGenerator, environment.logger)
    }
}
```

In my consumer I have the following:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackOutput.Target.UMD

group = "com.od"

plugins {
    application
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.6.0-1.0.1"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")
}


kotlin {

    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            binaries.executable()
            webpackTask {
                output.libraryTarget = UMD
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {

                val serializationVersion = "1.3.1"
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$serializationVersion")
                implementation("io.jvaas:jvaas-observe")

            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {

                
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting


        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    add("kspJvm", "io.jvaas:jvaas-observe")
    // add("kspJs", "io.jvaas:jvaas-observe") // <--- fails if enabled
    //ksp("io.jvaas:jvaas-observe")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.od.demo.Main"
}
```

applications/od-server/src/**commonMain**/kotlin/com/od/demo/**Blah.kt**

```
package com.od.demo

import io.jvaas.observe.Observable

@Observable
class Blah {

    var test1: String = ""
    var test2: Int = 0
    var test3: Array<String> = arrayOf()

}
```

This correctly gets processed when the **kspJvm** option is enabled and correctly outpus a file at

applications/od-server/build/generated/ksp/**jvmMain**/kotlin/com/od/demo/**BlahO.kt**

If I enable it for **kspJs**, it fails

```
add("kspJs", "io.jvaas:jvaas-observe")


Execution failed for task ':applications:od-server:compileProductionExecutableKotlinJs'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':applications:od-server:compileProductionExecutableKotlinJs' property 'entryModule$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Collection has more than one element.
```

I've tried the usual gradle build --info / --debug / --scan but it's not clear where I can start looking to resolve this issue.

As mentioned above, I made a demo project to demonstrate the error:
https://github.com/janvladimirmostert/observable-demo

Any ideas on how to resolve that error?

Comment: Bug report filed here: https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/744

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed in https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/744 but I'm not sure if it has been released yet.